# Large arraylist, finding the product of certain amount of elements

Tags: java

I have an array list which contains the numbers below, and what i am trying to do is find the product of every 16 numbers.

```
          try {
                for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++) {
            System.out.println(list.subList(z, z + 16));
```

the above prints this

```
[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2]
[3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4]
[1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9]
[6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1]
etc......
```

my solution was to put every line above in to an array and find the product of that array.However i am stuck, was wondieering if anyone can provide me a few pointers on about how to take a hit at this

```
        list.subList(z, z + 16);
              for(int i = 0; i < list.subList(z, z+16).size();i++){
                Ar[i] = list.get(z);
            }
```

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Comment: just checking. if you have something like 1,2,3...32, will you have 2 products, one for 1~16 and another for 17~32? Or will you have one for 1~16, another for 2~17 and so on? If it's the latest, maybe you could store intermediate results, since the product of 2~17 is basically the product of 1~16 x 17...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` then you could do

```
 ArrayList <ArrayList> listofList = new ArrayList ();

for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z = z + 16) {

     int endpoint = z + 16;  // check to see not bigger than 1000
     ArrayList thisList = list.subList(z, endpoint);
     listOfList.add (thisList);
     System.out.println(thisList);
}
```

But there again you may want to just add up as you go.

```
ArrayList thisList = list.subList(z, endpoint);
int prod = 1;
for (int x : thisList) {
   prod *= x;
}
```

If you look at the printout that you are showing, you will that it is just moving one number each time - not what you want.

Comment: i have to find the largest product of 16 consecutive numbers, so what i had is what i need. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: My solution gives you the way to calculate the product of each 16 consecutive numbers. So what is you question then?

Comment: i was respondind to this"If you look at the printout that you are showing, you will that it is just moving one number each time - not what you want."

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. Instead of printing out the answer, you coudl add it to an array or something and use it later. Fyi I subbed the zeroes for 1's so I knew it was working.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int[] arr = {7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 4, 9};

        int counter = 0;
        int product = 1;
        for (int i : arr)
        {
            if (counter < 16)
            {
                product *= i;
                counter++;
            }

            if (counter >= 16)
            {
                System.out.println(product);
                product = 1;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what printed (again I subbed the zeroes for ones):

```
60011280
34292160
102876480
```